# Creating a script to replace values in files when being pushed into S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using AWS S3 Bucket to upload CSV files regarding sensor data. Once uploaded into the bucket a python lambda function is triggered to provide the 'last update' time as an epoch and the 'direction' and 'speed' in a JSON format.

**The initial upload via CSV**

| LAST UPDATE | DIRECTION | SPEED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/30/2021 9:51:01 AM | 146 | 4.22 |

**The output from lambda function**

`1619776261 {'DIRECTION': '146', 'SPEED': '4.22'}`

In order to demonstrate how this works, I was thinking of creating a script to replace the date and values in each of the uploaded files with random values and automatically pushing up to the s3 bucket every 30 secs or 1 minute. However, I am not sure how to go about writing this script so would appreciate any insights anyone has to offer! Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to know how to write a script which uploads the file to s3 every 1 min so that your lambda can modify that, right ?

Comment: yes please! @KnowledgeGainer

Comment: Do you have that script which is uploading random details to s3 ?

Comment: I am talking about function which does the initial upload, only __upload__ not about uploading every 1 min or anything.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding. At the moment I am just manually uploading the CSV into the S3 bucket

Comment: Okay now I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This can be your logic,
So the overview is,

**Cloudwatch** will start a trigger every 1 min, that trigger will be a lambda function which will upload the csv file to the **S3**, later since S3 is enabled with a trigger, it will trigger another lambda function which will perform the processing as you have mentioned in the question, and you can later save that data back or use it for any other purpose.

Before setting a **cloudwatch**, first we need our 1st **lambda** function which will do the uploading.

For random data creation and converting it to dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'LAST UPDATE':str(datetime.now()),'DIRECTION':str(random.randint(100,200)),'SPEED':str(random.random()+random.randint(1,5))[:4]},index=[0])
```

Output:

[image]

and storing it in s3, you can use this function inside your 1st lambda function,

**You might have to do some modification in this code**

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
import boto3
s3_res = boto3.resource('s3')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'LAST UPDATE':str(datetime.now()),'DIRECTION':str(random.randint(100,200)),'SPEED':str(random.random()+random.randint(1,5))[:4]},index=[0])
csv_df = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_df)
s3_res = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_res.Object(bucket, '{0}.csv'.format(str(uuid.uuid4()))).put(Body=csv_df.getvalue())
```

Now to invoke this function every 1 min,

You can follow this guide--> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

This will invoke your lambda function every 1 min.

Then your trigger will do the work as you have mentioned in the code.

Comment: Thanks so much! My only question is: is there a way to define the S3 bucket in which the above is saved into?

Comment: @databasefoe define the s3 bucket means ?

Comment: ```obj = s3.Object(bucket_name='boto3', key='test.py')```  like so? Apologies, I am new to this

Comment: @databasefoe `s3_res.Object(bucket, '{0}.csv'.format(str(uuid.uuid4()))).put(Body=csv_df.getvalue())` in this line __bucket__ will the name of your bucket in which you are are going to store file. File name will be automatically generated using uuid. __key__ = `'{0}.csv'.format(str(uuid.uuid4()))`